# 3D data as heat map with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have this dataset with three variables:

```
       modu  mnc       eff
1 0.3181054 0.02 0.4721769
2 0.3208097 0.06 0.4715646
3 0.3034289 0.06 0.4718367
4 0.3040065 0.06 0.4721088
5 0.3090475 0.02 0.4735374
6 0.2918505 0.02 0.4742177
```

(full dataset here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmsq5opdjq949ie/new_pareto.csv?dl=0)

Which I would like to plot with ggplot2 on a 2d plot where x = modu, y = eff, and color = mnc.

I started this, but I'm obviously doing something wrong...

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- read.csv("/new_pareto.csv", check.names = FALSE)

p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x = modu, y = eff, fill = mnc))
p <- p + geom_tile()
p <- p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100))
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 1))
p <- p + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 1))
p <- p + coord_equal()
p <- p + theme_bw()

print(zp1)
```

Any idea on how to go about it? Do I need to somehow set a grid and let my x and y data fit into it?

Thanks!

Comment: one thing that jumps out... your x and y are numeric not discrete

Comment: indeed, do I need to resample them?

Comment: It looks like you're not using the `mnc` variable, do you really want `eff` mapped both to y and fill color?

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably want to use `stat_summary2d`. `geom_tile` makes sense when you have evenly spaced data with a single color value per equal-sized tile. You've got irregularly spaced data, that doesn't cover your full space:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = modu, y = eff, color = eff)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

and `stat_summary2d` lets you bin it into squares and specify a summary function for the points that fall within:

```
p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x = modu, y = eff))
p <- p + stat_summary2d(aes(z = mnc), fun = mean) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.27, 0.39)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.42, 0.54))

p + coord_equal() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

So here we specified `z = eff`, and it's the `z` values that get passed to the `fun` function, in this case `mean`.

You could also use `stat_summary_hex` instead to get a hexagonal binning instead of a square tile binning. Since you're using `coord_equal`, I set the x and y ranges to be the same so that the bins would be squares not rectangles.